# incomplete query when adding a radio button to the table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to make an "edit record" function in my PHP file where you can edit a row using a Radio Button.

My table "book" has 15 records inside it. It works just fine but when I add a row in my database, it malfunctions and displays:

1. A table with incomplete data.
2. No buttons.
3. 500 Server Error (rarely).

I'm new to PHP and self-studying about the functions and syntax. Any help would be appreciated :)

**Here is my PHP code:**

```
<?php
include 'config.php';

session_start();

$sql = "SELECT * from book";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($count == 0){
    $error = "There is no books in the list";

}

<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="editinfo.php">

    <table border="1" style="width:80%" align="center">
        <tr>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>ISBN</th>
            <th>Title of the book</th>
            <th>Cost</th>
            <th>Copies</th>
            <th>Edition</th>
            <th>Publisher</th>
            <th>Copy Year</th>
            <th>Shelf Number</th>
            <th>Subject</th>

        </tr>
        <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

            $ISBN = $row['ISBN'];
            $Title = $row['Title'];
            $Cost = $row['Cost'];
            $Copies = $row['Copies'];
            $Edition = $row['Edition'];
            $Publisher = $row['Publisher'];
            $CopyYr = $row['CopyYr'];
            $Shelf = $row['ShelfNo'];
            $Subject = $row['SubName'];

            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><input name="editradio" type="radio" value="<?php echo $ISBN; ?>" checked></td>
                <td><?php echo $ISBN; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $Title; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $Cost; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $Copies; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $Edition; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $Publisher; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $CopyYr; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $Shelf; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $Subject; ?></td>
            </tr>

            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </table>
    <br>
    <table align="center" style="width:20%">
        <tr>
            <th><input type="submit" name="editinfo" value="Edit Selected"></th>
</form>
<form action="bookslist.php" method="post">
    <th><input type="submit" value="Back"/></th>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

**SQL Dump:**

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `book`
--

CREATE TABLE `book` (
  `ISBN` varchar(14) NOT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Cost` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `Copies` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `Edition` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `Publisher` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `CopyYr` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `ShelfNo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `SubName` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `book`
--

INSERT INTO `book` (`ISBN`, `Title`, `Cost`, `Copies`, `Edition`, `Publisher`, `CopyYr`, `ShelfNo`, `SubName`) VALUES
('0123704901', 'Computer Architecture: A Quantitative Approach', '24.95', 10, 4, 'Morgan Kaufmann', 2006, 11, 'ICT'),
('0123944244', 'Digital Design and Computer Architecture', '52.57', 10, 2, 'Morgan Kaufmann', 2012, 11, 'ICT'),
('0124077269', 'Computer Organization and Design', '75.74', 10, 5, 'Morgan Kaufmann', 2013, 13, 'ICT'),
('0205973361', 'Psychology', '158.53', 10, 4, 'Pearson', 2014, 14, ''),
('0321696867', 'University Physics with Modern Physics', '225.76', 10, 13, 'Addison-Wesley', 2011, 12, 'Science'),
('0321740904', 'Physics for Scientists and Engineers: A Strategic ', '228.16', 10, 3, 'Addison-Wesley', 2012, 15, 'Science'),
('0321884078', 'Thomas'' Calculus: Early Transcendentals', '198.89', 10, 13, 'Pearson', 2013, 12, 'Mathematics'),
('0470879521', 'Physics', '209.38', 10, 9, 'John Wiley and Sons', 2012, 11, 'Science'),
('0596802358', 'Data Analysis with Open Source Tools', '26.69', 10, 1, 'O''Reilly Media', 2010, 14, 'ICT'),
('099040207X', 'SQL Database for Beginners', '22.49', 10, 1, 'LearnToProgram, Incorporated ', 2014, 15, 'ICT'),
('1285057090', 'Calculus', '245.84', 10, 10, 'Cengage Learning', 2013, 13, 'Mathematics'),
('1429261781', 'Psychology', '152.54', 10, 10, 'Worth Publishers', 2011, 14, ''),
('1449600069', 'The Essentials of Computer Organization and Archit', '215.95', 10, 3, 'Jones & Bartlett Learning', 2010, 11, 'ICT'),
('1452257876', 'Qualitative Data Analysis: A Methods Sourcebook', '72.42', 10, 3, 'SAGE Publications, Inc', 2013, 12, 'ICT'),
('1590597699', 'Beginning Database Design: From Novice to Professi', '25.83', 10, 1, 'Apress', 2007, 15, 'ICT');

-- --------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: `<input name="editradio" type="radio" value="<?php echo $ISBN; ?>" checked>` why `value="<?php echo $ISBN; ?>`?

Comment: Also please add the code where you can edit and upload a new row

Comment: @skeeedrow After submit you forwarding to the path in action and there you have the problem.

Comment: @Shinratensei to assign a value to the radio. is it wrong? I'm new to PHP

Comment: @Shinratensei the error is when I retrieve the table using select statement. there's no problem in the edit function

Comment: @SkeeedRow No, that's not wrong, it's actually necessary I suppose. Sorry, I copied the wrong thing. I meant, why was it checked? You're iterating over all of them creating a new checked button every time, it's not necessary. Anyway, the problem is not there.

Comment: @SkeeedRow and please do what I told you: add the part of the code that allows you to upload a new row. Otherwise I can't tell where's the problem

Comment: @Shinratensei do I have to edit my post? sorry I'm kinda new here haha

Comment: @Shinratensei I mean how can I put the code you are requesting?

Comment: @SkeeedRow well, you have to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46193079/edit) your post and paste the code I'm requesting.